# ComboBox & ON_WM_CONTEXTMENU - sometimes have to double-right-click

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

We call `ON_WM_CONTEXTMENU()` inside `BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP` in our dialog class. However with a combo-box control, right-clicking over the drop-down arrow on the right side triggers a context menu. But with the rest of the control, the user has to *double*-right-click to get this working.

[image]

What could be the cause? Is there something special about the little down-arrow?